# GoogleMaps API + KML Layers + select all

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, checkbox

I have one HTML code with some JavaScript functions, to show Google Maps with some [KML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) layers.

The layers are loaded with this code:

```
layers [0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.jourdan.org.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/NOVABRASILIA.kmz',
                        {preserveViewport: true, suppressInfoWindows: true});
```

(one for each layer)

The function to show the layers is this one:

```
function bairros(i) {
    if (layers[i].getMap() === null) {
        layers[i].setMap(map);
    }
    else {
        layers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

And I have some checkboxes to show or hide the layers.

The layers/checkboxes are working quite well. The problem happens when I try to show all the layers.

The function I'm using is this one:

```
function checkAll(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('bairros');
    for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].click();
    }
}
```

The function "works". It checks the checkboxes and uncheck them too... but... the layers just don't appear.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit on the number of layers. See *[KML Support in Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport)* for more information.

Comment: I didn't see that... dammit...

39 layers.... hahaha... for now... and I need more than that. "bairros" is like neighborhood, or district here in Brazil.

well.... thank you... I'll see if I can try something else... maybe Bing Maps.... Thanks man!